# Oracle - Create a view with data from different table as column names

Tags: oracle, view, dynamicquery

Create view with fields from another table as column headers

I've got two tables that I'd like to combine into a view.

The first table contains the structure:

## PhoneNumberType  PhoneNumberTypeName

101                       Mobile

102                        Home

103                      Work

The second table contains the actual data that will be stored, and the columns reference the ID of the first table:

## PhoneNumberType    PhoneNumber   PersonId

101         90354351        1001

102         98345634    1001

103         92345123   1002

What I'd like to get as a result in a view:

## Mobile   Home     Work     PersonId

9035435   98345634 Null     1001

Null      Null     92345    1002

Basically I would like to combine 2 tables and create a view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PIVOT` in this case as following:

```
-- CREATING SAMPLE DATA
WITH FIRST_TABLE(PhoneNumberType, PhoneNumberTypeName)
AS
(
SELECT 101, 'Mobile' from dual union all
SELECT 102, 'Home' from dual union all
SELECT 103, 'Work' from dual
),
second_table (PhoneNumberType, PhoneNumber, PersonId)
AS
(
select 101, 90354351, 1001 from dual union all
select 102, 98345634, 1001 from dual union all
select 103, 92345123, 1002 from dual
)
--
-- ACTUAL QUERY STARTS FROM HERE
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            S.PERSONID,
            S.PHONENUMBER,
            F.PHONENUMBERTYPENAME
        FROM
            FIRST_TABLE F
            JOIN SECOND_TABLE S ON F.PHONENUMBERTYPE = S.PHONENUMBERTYPE
    ) PIVOT (
        MAX ( PHONENUMBER )
        FOR PHONENUMBERTYPENAME
        IN ( 'Mobile',
        'Home',
        'Work' )
    )
ORDER BY
    1
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d32c02e06b9d44fb292c77407ccefc84)

Cheers!!

Comment: You can also use `listagg` instead of `max` in case someone has [two mobile](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=481e86e5270e3c48e583d9364c6b6c9b) numbers.

Comment: @ponderstibbons, I can. But it depends on the requirement of questioner. And yes, good idea.